# Не работает Eclipse. Скомпилированный EXE работает только на данном компьютере

Tags: java

Я работаю в среде программирования *Eclipse*. Компилирую *EXE* файлы через *Launch4J*.

Тестировал своё приложение на моём компьютере - всё работает, но на других компьютерах приложение не запускается, выходит сообщение:

> Java Virtual Machine - A Java exception has occured.

Полазил на [форумах](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662588/java-virtual-machine-launcher-error-a-java-exception-has-occurred), а конкретнее [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453100/ant-not-working-in-eclipse-kepler-java-virtual-machine-launcher-a-java-except). В общем, как сказали люди в первой ссылке, проблема в каком-то *Ant*. Поменял настройки, как там сказали, но *Eclipse* в итоге вывел сообщение

> Specified Ant home does not contain a 'lib' directory.

С тех пор *Eclipse* работать перестал. Нажимаю на кнопку <kbd>Run</kbd> (запустить приложение), выводится окошко <kbd>Run As</kbd>, в котором список, состоящий из двух элементов <kbd>Ant Build</kbd> и <kbd>Ant Build...</kbd>, а ниже кнопка <kbd>ОК</kbd>.

Ну выбрал первый, потом второй, выходит сообщение

> Error - Build Failed. Reason: Unable to find an Ant file to run.

Подскажите, что мне делать?

Приложение нужно срочно доделать сегодня, к вечеру.

Comment: А если запустить ваш exe-файл из командной строки, может там будет текст исключения. Если не будет, советуют собрать с 'Header type: Console' на вкладке Header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Работает только на одном компьютере, так как, возможно, на других компьютерах не стоит нужная версия Java JRE.

2) Из-за того, что в Eclipse я поменял настройки Ant, потерялось её расположение, следовательно приложение не запускалось. Если что, то в настройках "Ant Path" нужно указать путь к Java JRE, где собственно и находится папка lib.